# Cox in R: how can I interpret the strange output data I've received?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, p-value, cox-regression

I am conducting a survival analysis using the gene expression values (converted to z-scores) from a certain gene and event free survival time for 249 patients. I am a beginner to this.

Here is my code:

> finaldata$SurvObj <- with(finaldata, Surv(efst, status == 2))
>
> finaldata$SurvObj
>
> res.cox1 <- coxph(SurvObj ~ Zscore, data =  finaldata)
>
> summary(res.cox1)

And here is the output:

```
coxph(formula = SurvObj ~ Zscore, data = finaldata)

  n= 247, number of events= 140 
   (2 observations deleted due to missingness)

         coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)   

Zscore 0.5878    1.8001   0.2118 2.776   0.0055 
---
Signif. codes:  0 0.001  0.01  0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

       exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95

Zscore       1.8     0.5555     1.189     2.726

Concordance= 0.561  (se = 0.025 )

Likelihood ratio test= 7.92  on 1 df,   p=0.005

Wald test            = 7.71  on 1 df,   p=0.006

Score (logrank) test = 7.74  on 1 df,   p=0.005
```

efst is the event free survival time for patients, the status is whether they are dead or alive (1 is alive, 2 is dead), and Zscore is the Z-Score value for the expression of the gene in question for each of the patients (to understand whether the expression is relatively high or low).

However, I find it highly improbable that I am receiving such p-values and that leads me to think that I have definitely done something incorrectly since this is my first time trying this out.

How can I find any errors I have made, how can I fix them, and how should I interpret this data?

Comment: Looks fine to me. The hazard ratio for Zscore is 1.8 (1.2 - 2.7) with a corresponding significant p-value. If that doesn't match your expectations, then perhaps your commands to calculate the Zscore has errors. Incidentally, you can just do this: `res.cox1 <- coxph(Surv(efst, status) ~ Zscore, data = finaldata)`

Comment: Oh, and I find it hard to believe that a Zscore can give a hazard ratio of 1.8. I'd triple check your calculation for this variable. Is it really a Zscore? Maybe `dput` your data (and your commands).

Comment: Looks pretty weird to me. I've never seen anyone try to put a Surv-object back into a dataframe.`res.cox1 <- coxph(Surv(efst, status == 2)) ~ Zscore, data = finaldata)`

Comment: @42. Your advice about putting a survival object into a data frame is good. There's no need, since if the status or time changes for anyone, you have to update the survival object as well. ;)

Comment: 140 events is a fairly large number and would seem sufficient for a HR approaching 2 to be significant. The power of survival analysis depends to a large extent on the number of events and power analysis is to a first approximation similar to that of logistic regression (i.e a binomial test).

Comment: Edward. I rechecked the output and realized I made a big mistake on the coefficient/HR.

Comment: @Edward Thank you for your response! I originally had gene expression data that was RMA transformed, and I used those values to calculate the Z-Scores. Is that perhaps what is causing the issue? If so, what would you recommend that I do instead?

Comment: You could describe the study design and the data gathering effort.

Comment: @Ankita. From what you posted, there is no error. I suggest you start another question with a new angle. I don't know what RMA means and I'm not a gene expert, so I'll just wish you good luck. ☺

Comment: @42 Thank you for your response! I obtained the gene expression values that were originally from an Affymetrix microarray and had been RMA transformed for 249 neuroblastoma patients from the TARGET database. I then calculated the Z-score value for each patient using the expression value of my gene of interest (NEK2) for each patient, subtracting the mean (from the expression values of ALL the genes from ALL the patients), and dividing by the standard deviation (once again, from all genes across all patients). This is then what I put into my cox regression, along with state and survival time.

Comment: I'd like to see the output of `summary (finaldata$Zscore)`.

Comment: Min = -0.82479, 1st Qu. = -0.08007 , Median =  0.18979, Mean = 0.17191, 3rd Qu. = 0.48731, Max. = 1.49675.

Comment: That doesn't look like a Zscore to me. The mean should be 0. How did you calculate this? Please show the R command(s).

Comment: I actually calculated the z-scores using java because I am far more comfortable in java (I am very new to programming in general, but I know more java than R and it was easier for me to read in so many files and values in java opposed to R), and used R only for the cox regression. Since there is no easy way to calculate z-scores in java, I'm afraid that my code is a bit long and convoluted, but I would gladly show you the code if you are comfortable with Java. What would be an easy way to calculate in R (with 249 separate .txt files)? I was not able to get it to work in R. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry - I'm no good with java. But it can't be that hard to standardize a vector. (X-mean(X))/sd(X).

Comment: @AnkitaM So you are working with a person who has access through https://ocg.cancer.gov/programs/target/data-matrix ? There _are_ easy ways to work with multiple files in R but I'm not sure that is needed. Calculating z scores should not be needed. You should be able to use the RMA data without applying the z transform. The reason that your mean is not 0 as Edward was asking is that the RMA data has already been log transformed. So you were starting with data that was probably highly skewed and non-negative. See https://support.bioconductor.org/p/50480/

Comment: @AnkitaM Given what I am reading here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6704366/ your results appear sensible.

Comment: @42 Thank you, things are starting to make a lot more sense now. Yes, my original RMA data was skewed and non-negative, so this means that I can then just use the original NEK2 values in my cox regression, correct (in other words, I don't need expression values of all the other genes)? The reason I calculated z-scores was to be able to tell whether NEK2 expression was high or low relative to the expression of other genes. Thanks, Ankita.